# Unable to display image reactjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I have saved an image using postman for an API i created. 
The way image is being saved is:

```
const newProduct = new Product({
    name: req.body.name,
    referenceId: createReferenceId(),
    category: req.body.category,
    image: {
      data: fs.readFileSync(req.body.image),
      contentType: "image/jpg"
    },
    metadata: req.body.metadata
  });
  newProduct
    .save()
    .then(product => res.json(product))
    .catch(err => res.json(err));
```

My mongoose schema looks like this:

```
const ProductSchema = new Schema({
 name: { type: String, required: true },
  referenceId: { type: String, required: true },
  category: { type: String, required: true },
  image: { contentType: String, data: Buffer },
  metadata: { type: String }
});
```

My stored data looks like this:

```
[255, 216, 255, 224, 0, 16, 74, 70, 73, 70, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 100, 0, 100, 0, 0, 255, 225, 13, 5, 69, 120, 105, 102, 0, 0, 77, 77, 0, 42, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 7, 1, 18, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 26, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 98, 1, 27, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 106, 1, 40, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 49, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 20, 0, 0, 0, 11]
```

I want to Display this saved image in reactJS? I am confused how could I do that. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can save your image as a dataURL. The following is a promise i created in-order to extract the image data from a dropzone component.

```js
const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.readAsDataURL(filesToUpload[0]);
    reader.onload = () => {
      if (reader.result) {
        resolve(reader.result);
      } else {
        reject(Error('Failed converting to base64'));
      }
    };
});
```

You can then access the data using the `then()` method in promise.

```js
promise.then((result) => {
  // This is the result
  console.log(result);
}, (err) => {
  console.log(err);
});
```

Once you retrieve the dataURL post it to your API. Then you can easily use the `src` attribute in `<img>` to display the image.

Hope this helps. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Convert the array buffer to base64 and use that variable inside your html part.

```
let arrayBuffer = "Your data from api";

var base64Val = window.btoa(
                 new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer).reduce((data, byte) => 
                    data + String.fromCharCode(byte), ''
                 )
             );

<img src={`data:image/jpeg;base64,${base64Val}`} />
```